# Retrieve ArrayList Elements from AJAX success function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet which adds up the following into a JSONObject, rscurbatsmen is the resultset and clmmodel_batsman is a class which has the attributes playerid, playername, playerscore. How I'm gonna retrieve the elements from my JSP with AJAX function as I did for other variables.

```
 ArrayList curbatsmen = new ArrayList(); 
       while(rscurbatsmen.next()){

       clmmodel_batsman cb = new clmmodel_batsman();
       cb.playerid = new String();
       cb.playerid = rscurbatsmen.getString("playerid");
       cb.playername= new String();
       cb.playername = rscurbatsmen.getString("playerfname");
       cb.playerscore = new String();
       cb.playerscore = rscurbatsmen.getString("runsscored");
       curbatsmen.add(cb);                   

       }

       json.put("curbatsmen", curbatsmen);
```

Following is my AJAX code which I retrieved other variables I needed

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        (function ajaxInterval() {
            $.ajax({  
                url:'clmcontrol_livematchupdate',
                type:'post', 
                dataType: 'json', 

                success: function(data) {  

                    $('#lblscore').html(data.score);//lblscore is a label
                    //Here i need to retrieve elements one by one in order to set the values in particular labels




                },
                complete: function() {
                    // Schedule the next request when the current one has been completed
                    setTimeout(ajaxInterval, 4000);
                }  
            });
        })();


    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON there should be a node `curbatsmen` which will evaluate to an array of objects, looking something like this:

```
[
 {"playerId":1,"playerName":"test","playerScore":"score"},
 {"playerId":1,"playerName":"test","playerScore":"score"},
 {"playerId":1,"playerName":"test","playerScore":"score"}
]
```

As such, you can use the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.curbatsmen.length; i++){
    batsman = data.curbatsmen[i];
    $("#lblscore").html(batsman.playerScore);
```

}

Or, whatever it is you actually want to do with the player names/scores etc.